# How to Find and Replace in a Word document using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

My goal is to find every mention of "Project:" in a Word document and change it to "**Project:**".

My code currently copies information from Excel to a Word file but I can't figure out formatting.

This is the code I have written thus far. Any thoughts or ideas on how to make this happen in my code.

```
Sub Write_Project_Inv()        
    
    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    
    Dim table As Range
    Set table = Range("A2", "X10")
    
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add        
    
    With objWord
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        
        For Each Row In table.Rows
            
            .Selection.Typetext ("Project: " + Row.Cells(1, 1).Text + Row.Cells(1, 2).Text)
            .Selection.typeparagraph
            
            .Selection.Typetext ("Project Overview: " + Row.Cells(1, 3).Text)
            .Selection.typeparagraph
            
            .Selection.typeparagraph
        Next Row
        
    End With        
    
    With objDoc
        
        objDoc.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        objDoc.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
                    
        objDoc.Range.Find.ClearFormatting
        objDoc.Range.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        objDoc.Range.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold = True
        
        With objDoc.Range.Find
            .Text = "Project:"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            
        End With
        
        objDoc.Range.Find.Execute
        objDoc.Range.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: Record a macro whilst using Find and Replace in Word and you will get the syntax required to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run this code in Excel?

Do you just want make non-bold "Project:" to bold "Project:?

Then Just let `.Replacement.Text = ""` to `.Replacement.Text = "Project"`
You'll get it.

BTW： Wouldn't you want "Project:" in your question, why is your code `.Text = "Project"` "Project" without colon?

That's make the property **[Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.text)** of object **[Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find)** equal with the [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.replacement.text) of object **[Replacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.replacement)**. You wrongly set the Text of Replacement to "", that will clear all found string "Project".

[Finding and Replacing Text or Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/finding-and-replacing-text-or-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

All the properties assignment and methods must applied to the same Find object. Therefore must take place in the same with statement. Try the following modifications.

```
With objDoc
        
        objDoc.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        objDoc.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
                    
        'objDoc.Range.Find.ClearFormatting                    'deleted
        'objDoc.Range.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting        'deleted   
        'objDoc.Range.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold = True       'deleted
        
        With objDoc.Range.Find
            .ClearFormatting                       'added
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting           'added   
            .Replacement.Font.Bold = True          'added 
            .Text = "Project"
            .Replacement.Text = "Project"          'edited
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll                    'added
        End With
        
        'objDoc.Range.Find.Execute                            'deleted
        'objDoc.Range.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll      'deleted
        
    End With
```

Sidenote: The outer with loop in this form unnecessary.